# angularjs ui-router set active link doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to set an active link
on the current tab like

```
in jade
ul.nav.navbar-nav
                            li(ng-class="{ active: $state.includes('index') }")
                                a(ui-sref='index') Home
                            li(ng-class="{ active: $state.includes('post') }")
                                a(ui-sref='post') Post
 html
<li ng-class="{ active: $state.includes('index') }"><a ui-sref="index" href="#/">Home</a></li>
              <li ng-class="{ active: $state.includes('post') }"><a ui-sref="post" href="#/post">Post</a></li>




js   .config(function($stateProvider,RestangularProvider,PostProvider,PostsProvider,MediaProvider) {
            $stateProvider
                .state('index', {
                    url: '/',
                    templateUrl: 'admin/views/index.html',
                    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
                })
                .state('post', {
                    url: '/post',
                    templateUrl: 'admin/views/post/index.html',
                    resolve: {
                        posts: function(Posts){
                            return Posts.all();
                        }
                    },
                    controller: 'PostIndexCtrl'
                })
```

but it doesn't work. 
But if I try to check it:

```
.controller('PostIndexCtrl', function ($scope,posts,$state) {
        $scope.posts = posts;
        console.log($state.includes('post'));
    })
```

give me true.

Do you know what's the problem ?

Comment: Is `$state` available on `$scope` in the place you're doing that?

Comment: I've thought of the same thing (but it's quite odd because best practice say the scripts go close to </body> tag) my deploy https://gist.github.com/whisher/8646820

Comment: but all in all in MainCtrl I've got the reference to $state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.run(function ($state,$rootScope, $log) {
   $rootScope.$state = $state;
});
```

You need to put $state on $rootScope if you want to access it.
A great thanks to the ui-router folks :)

Comment: Does `$state.transitionTo('index');` contribute to the solution?  If not, perhaps edit it out to avoid confusion?